# Автоподстановка в Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Стоит студия с С++ решарпером. При объявлении переменных всплывает список возможных автодополнений, причем довольно часто какое-то из имён меня устраивает (точнее я так же бы назвал переменную), и это экономило бы время, но есть НО - стиль. Я пишу верблюдом (firstSecondThird), а он предлагает с "_" (first_second_third). Знает ли кто-нибудь, где это можно настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, где это сделать, если установлен ReSharper (возможно, его наличие необязательно). Идём RESHARPER->Options->Code Editing->_нужный_язык->Naming Style